# MongoDB Models not importing into mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, npm, mongoose

I cloned a github project and cannot submit models to the mongoDb database. the project I [cloned](https://github.com/ikismail/Vue-ShoppingCart) is a simple shopping cart app.

I followed the readme.md instructions and created a free mongodb cluster.

**[MongoDB Compass Info Clipboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa42n.jpg)**

I'm trying to connect with this link

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://orhanisadmin:this_password_is_invalid@cluster0.pu1be.mongodb.net/orhandb?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {    useNewUrlParser: true });
```

**Models**

- product.js

  ```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose')
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema
   var ProductSchema = new Schema({
       productName: String,
       productDescription: String,
       productCategory: String,
       productPrice: String,
       productImage: String,
       productSeller: String,
       isBestProduct: Boolean,
       isTopProduct: Boolean,
       productRating: Number
   })  module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
  ```
- shipping.js

  ```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose')
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema

   var ShippingDetailSchema = new Schema({
       address1: String,
       address2: String,
       country: String,
       zipCode: String,
       shippingDate: String,
       products: Array,
       userId: String,
       totalPrice: String
   })

   module.exports = mongoose.model('ShippingDetail', ShippingDetailSchema)
  ```
- user.js

  ```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose')
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema

   var UserSchema = new Schema({
       firstName: String,
       lastName: String,
       fullName: String,
       email: String,
       isAdmin: Boolean,
       password: String,
       createdOn: String
   })    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
  ```

Comment: You should use `db.collection.save()`. Take a look at [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the collection is created automatically when you save the model, IF there's no collection named it. As you know, in initial state, there's no collections on the database.
If you save some data to database in controller, the collections are created automatically. Please refer the code below.

How to connect to DB using mongoose

```
const mongoDB = "YOUR_DB_URL";
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.on('connected', function(){
  console.log("MongoDB is connected to this app.")
});
```

How to save model...

```
var payload = req.body.payload;
var user = new UserInfo();
//your action...
user.save();
```

Comment: Hmm, I see. Maybe, connecting to the database server that is hosted on cloud.mongodb.com takes some time so please wait until the msg logged in console.
Or please check your internet connection.